# How to update and specific Object in the useState Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the
`props.setSelectValue((prevState: any) => ([...prevState, {control: props.data.control, value:itemValue}]))`
to update and array of objects, but it is appending value to a previous object and I would like just to update when the key is already in the object. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the values to undefined  if they aren't defined in prevState

```js
props.setSelectValue((prevState: any) => ([...prevState, {
  control: prevState.control ? props.data.control : undefined,
  value: prevState.value ? itemValue : undefined
}]))
```